# How to handle custom view touch event only on opaque(visible) area

Tags: android, android-custom-view, touch-event

Hi I am trying to detect touch event only on the opaque(visible)area of the custom view. For example, the rectangular view and circle view which has a transparent area inside it (the left screen below). But according to [Android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), each "View" occupies a rectangular area on the screen (so its boundary should look like the right screen where red area is the transparent area).

Could anyone guide me to how can I detect touch event only when user click on blue area of the view ? 
Thank you in advance.

[image: view boundary]

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if you draw your shape to a `Bitmap`, and on the click event of the view, get the color value at that position, if alpha is 0 then you can return the function without doing anything, otherwise you can proceed.

One of my application I have done this for dragging multiple images in a single view, and Image can be of any shape, User only can drag a image if touch the visible area. So I am posting my block of code here

```
public boolean containsPoint(float scrnX, float scrnY) {
            // FIXME: need to correctly account for image rotation
            float[] XY = new float[] { scrnX, scrnY };
            Bitmap bitmap = getBimap();
            Matrix inv = new Matrix();
            mDrawMatrix.invert(inv);
            inv.mapPoints(XY);
            int x = Integer.valueOf((int) XY[0]);
            int y = Integer.valueOf((int) XY[1]);
            if (x < 0 || x > bitmap.getWidth() - 1 || y < 0 || y > bitmap.getHeight() - 1) {
                // continue;
                return false;
            }

            int col = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
            if (Color.alpha(col) != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```